# Receiving IQ with error 403 with type AUTH for last seen query

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am send  Packet to client given as below.

```
 <iq id="xoB6R-4" to="user1@xyz.xmpp" type="get">
       <query xmlns='jabber:iq:last'/>
</iq>
```

but in response i am receiving erro4 403.

```
   <iq id="xoB6R-4" to="admin@xyz.xmpp/testchat" from="user2@xyz.xmpp" type="error">
     <query xmlns="jabber:iq:last"></query>
     <error code="403" type="AUTH">
           <forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
     </error>
  </iq>
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html, the requesting entity needs to be subscribed to the presence information for the particular user, otherwise the user's server must not return last activity information but instead MUST return a  error in response to the last activity request.

Even admin users need to subscribe to the presence information in order to view the last activity for a particular user.